# What word should I use for "funeral"?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

The word I am looking for is the ceremony held when somebody has died.

I found *entombigo* and *enterigo* at lernu.net, and ReVo gives me *funebra*.

*Entombigo* and *enterigo* seems like perfect translations of *burial* which is the actual act of placing someones body or ashes in the ground.

*Funebra* is obviously an adjective, and the definition of *funebro* in PIV points to 'grief'. It says nothing about ceremonies.

What word should I use for *funeral*?

Answer (score 7):

The act of funeral/burial/entombment is usually called *entombigo*. *Enterigo* basically means the same.

*Funebro* is grief, mourning, but can more specifically mean mourning ceremony / obsequies / funeral service.

So, they have a little overlap, but a different focus.

See also in REVO:

- [entombigo (under tombo)](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/tomb.html#tomb.en0igo)
- [funebro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/funebr.html)

Comment: I had always assumed - as you say here - that *funebro* can refer to a *funebra ceremonio* - but now that I've considered the question as asked, I can't find that meaning justified anywhere. Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Krom mia vortaro revo mencias tiun sencon, kaj donas referencon interalie el la nova testamento ("La ĉefa tradukanto estis Rust, kaj la ĉefa kontrolanto estis A.E.Wackrill." -- vp) http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/funebr.html Mi ankaŭ trovis malmultajn aliajn tekstojn en la reto kun tiu uzo de la vorto, sed ŝajne en formalaj tekstoj pli kutimas *funebra ceremonio/soleno/diservo* ...

Comment: Sorry, brain switched to eo ... 

except for my dictionary (and my memory ;-) ), [revo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/funebr.html) includes this meaning, and gives i.a. a reference from the new testament (from 1912, whose main translator was Rust, and main proofreader Wackrill, according to WP). I also found a few texts in the web which use this meaning, but usually formal texts seem to prefer *funebra ceremonio/soleno/diservo* ...

Comment: I didn't notice which language you were writing in - in fact I looked at this for a minute and couldn't figure out why you had posted this twice. Very interesting, thanks. ReVo is based on PV - so apparently that meaning was edited out when PIV was produced. I wonder why. Wells seems to support PIV - and I'd be disinclined to disagree with both of them, but now I know that my initially feeling on the meanings here isn't totally out of left field. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Look through the entry of *funebro* in PIV, and you'll see ***funebraĵoj*** and at least two references to ***Funebra ceremonio.*** Benson (CEED) lists ***funebra procesio*** in addition to the other two.

Comment: Oh great! Which is the most common?

Comment: They all mean slightly different things. Another thing to consider is that in English as well there are different names for different types of services, depending on whether the body is present and so on. The expression you use will depend on what you're trying to say. The last "funeral" that I went to might be properly called a *funebra diservo* or *funebra meso*.

Answer (score 0):

Funebra Ceremonio = Mourning Ceremony

http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/funebr.html#funebr.0o